# pre-commit hook not working

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm trying to add a pre-commit hook to my project, When I run `./.git/hook/pre-commit` it gives proper result.
While committing variable OUTPUT is always empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=`git diff | flake8 --diff`


if [ -z "${OUTPUT}" ]
then
      echo "================== You are awesome ===================="
      echo "${OUTPUT}"
      exit 1
else
      echo ""
      echo "================== Your code stinks, Fix them ===================="
      echo ""
      echo "${OUTPUT}"
      exit 1
fi
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The hooks are run in a different environment.
Especially the PATH might not be set like you have it for your user.
Try using the whole path to the executables you call like `git` and `flake8` and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` shows you unstaged changes, i.e. changes that will *not* go in the commit. Within the `pre-commit` hook, the output will be empty unless you are doing a partial commit.

What you want is `git diff --staged` instead: it shows you the changes you are about to commit, and this is the part you want to check using `flake8`.

You can try running `git status` within the hook and look at "Changes to be committed:" and "Changes not staged for commit:" sections to understand what I mean.

Also, one of your `exit 1` should be an `exit 0` ;-).